# Структура/компановка приложения с двумя application Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Есть два приложения(проекта), которые используют одну и ту же библиотеку (проект с модулем Android Library).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**App** общается с **USB_Lib** прямым вызовом методов, а **USB_Lib** с **App** через interface с callback.
Когда приложения работают по одиночке, то все в порядке, но когда запускаются оба, то начинается конфликт за доступ к ресурсу (USB). Более того, возникла необходимость запускать **App2** при запуске **App1** и переключать их перелистованием экрана.
Первое, что пришло в голову это расширить interface **USB_Lib** для **App2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но как-то костили получаются: дважды передавать и анализировать содержимое принятых данных из **USB_Lib**, да и сам модуль должен работать только с одним приложением.

Решил идти другим путем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и импортировать **App2** в проект **App1**.

Тут возникает вопрос, как собрать одно приложение, проект которого состоит из одного модуля library и двух модулей application с разными package и надо что то еще прописывать в **gradle** в таком случае?
Главное сохранить автономность проекта **App2**, т.е. открыть проект, исправить код и отладить. **App1** всегда будет содержать **App2** и запускать его в зависимости от настроек, а вот **App2** должно иметь возможность работать как отдельное приложение. В любом случае на девайсе устанавливается либо только App1(со встроенным App2), либо только App2.

У кого какие идеи?

ЗЫ: рассматривал вариант сделать **USB_Lib** как Service, но нет надобности его все время держать в памяти, да и получиться как по пути расширения interface, хотя..

Comment: Сервис не обязан висеть в памяти, а тем более постоянно работать - он может запускаться по требованию любой из сторон и закрываться, когда к нему нет подключения. Почитайте про привязанные службы: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru. Но Вам не подойдёт ни то, ни другое, если оба приложения должны быть самостоятельными (когда APP2 не требует наличия на устройстве APP1 и наоборот) - в этом случае нужно разруливать сам конфликт доступа к USB.

Comment: Про "самостоятельность" уточню: на девайс ставиться либо только App1 со встроенным App2, либо только App2.